# favicon generator script give some minor error in php code

Tags: php, favicon

hi friends i m just create a demo of php favicon image generator when i trying to submit the image it shows the image in fixed size which you select but it also give a error thats is

```
Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\demo123\index.php on line 40
```

line 40

```
$ext = end(explode(".",strtolower(trim($_FILES["image"]["name"]))));
```

Comment: which php version are you using ?

Comment: You could Google the error message

Comment: i am using old version not new

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [PHP.net](http://bd.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php)

```
The following things can be passed by reference:

- Variables, i.e. foo($a)
- New statements, i.e. foo(new foobar())
- [References returned from functions][2]
```

So Change your code as below

```
$data = trim($_FILES["image"]["name"]);
$data = strtolower($data);
$data = explode(".",$data);
$ext = end($data);
```

**OR**

```
$ext = pathinfo($_FILES["image"]["name"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

Comment: thanks u friends now i sorted out the problem through yours thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to suppress the error message, you can add an "@" sign in front of that line.

Although I think the message might be caused by trying to pass along $_FILES[], but I can't test it atm.